# how to decode encoded json data from php in phonegap android

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, json

I want to store table data from the server to android local storage. but the issue is the table data might content special character like '<' or '>' even both. So when ajax call is made i all ways get  the sqllite error code 13 while inserting the data from the server. And if i try to store simple to localStorage from the server it working perfectly.
So i tried to encode the data in php and then send the data to android app in json form.But know it get blank data in the ajax data.
Here is the PHP code to encode data:

```
$select_table = 'select * from users';
$resultTableData = $conn->query($select_table);
while ($row1 = $resultTableData->fetch()) {
    $temporarydata[] = htmlentities(utf8_encode($row1),ENT_QUOTES);
}   
$data[$row] = $temporarydata;
mysql_close($con);
require_once('JSON.php');
$json = new Services_JSON();
echo ($json->encode($data));
```

Here is the ajax code in PhoneGap Android:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlServer + 'getDynamicFormData.php',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $.mobile.loading('show');
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log("ajax complete");
        createTable();
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        companyCode : companycode
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('value in data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data != null) {
            dynamic_tabledetails = data.Table_details;
            table_data = data;
            getTabledetails(dynamic_tabledetails);                  
        } else {
            alert("Error Message");
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log("Server is not responding... Please try again: "+thrownError);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a JSON answer, try looking about GSON, that may help you.

Comment: can you tell me whats GSON.

Comment: I tried to find about GSON but didn't got anything interesting. Isn't there any other way to decode the data with special characters like a complete query in table column and send to android app and decode it before reading.....